# Proof of compactness theorem from "Computability and Logic"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am having trouble understanding a proof of compactness theorem from "Computability and Logic" 5th ed. by Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey. I know that compactness theorem is as following

> A set of first-order logic sentences has a model if and only if every finite subset of the whole set has a model.

There are some lemmas such as 'finite character lemma' and 'model existence lemma' which the book proves instead of the compactness theorem itself, and I don't get the relevance of these lemmas with the compactness theorem. I have no idea what role each lemma plays in the proof of the compactness theorem and what does it have to do with each other lemmas. My question is:

1. If a set has satisfaction properties from lemma 13.1, then does it mean that the set is satisfiable? Is it a same thing to say 'a set is satisfiable' and 'a set has satisfaction properties'?
2. Does the lemma 13.2 (finite character lemma) prooves the 'if' direction of the compactness theorem, that is, a set of sentences has a model if every finite subset of the whole set has a model?
3. Does the lemma 13.3 (model existence lemma) prooves the 'only if' direction of the compactness theorem, that is, a set of sentences has a model only if every finite subset of the whole set has a model?

Comment: Can't you just take an ultraproduct of the models? You will need some choice for that, but you may need it anyway.

Comment: Well, I don't know what an ultraproduct is... I'm quite new to this kind of field.

Comment: Lemma 13.1 and 13.2 are linked to Lemma 13.3 (Model existence lemma) asserting that - under some condition - a set of sentences has a *model*. From this, Compactness follows; see page 155: "we get not only the compactness but also the Lowenheim–Skolem theorem". "So it ‘only’ remains to prove Lemma 13.3. The conclusion of Lemma 13.3 asserts the existence of an interpretation."

Comment: Lemma 13.3 follows from two others lemma: Lemma 13.5 (proved in Section 13.2/3) and Lemma 13.6 (proved in Section 13.4). That's all. *Maybe the structure of the proof can be streamlined*...